# Non-greedy matching for email headers

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

Given an email header input like this

```
Cc: "'Johnny sudson'" <johnny@quvx.com>, <martin@quvx.com>,
 <Joe@quvx.com>
```

how do I get lua to match only the email address? my intuition of it being `<(.*)>`  or something similar only matches in a greedy fashion, where as I need entry individually....

my use case is something like this.

```
for emails in  string.gmatch(all_cc,"<(.*)>" )
    do
```

so I can then work with each email address individually

Comment: <[^>]*> should do the trick.

Comment: works a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Non-greedy matching in Lua is represented in your case by `<.->`.